# Invoking <init> with bad arg 0, type 'Ljava/lang/String;' not instance of 'Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;'

Tags: android

I got stuck here, I searched on google but not find any answer related to my error

```
11-22 10:28:27.547 26448-26448/com.doctorq.app E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 8
11-22 10:28:27.547 26448-26448/com.doctorq.app E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
11-22 10:30:26.953 26448-26448/com.doctorq.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.doctorq.app, PID: 26448
                                                                 java.lang.VirtualMachineError: Invoking <init> with bad arg 0, type 'Ljava/lang/String;' not instance of 'Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;'
                                                                     at com.doctorq.app.StartSessionActivity.EndSessionSendData(StartSessionActivity.java:885)
                                                                     at com.doctorq.app.StartSessionActivity.onClick(StartSessionActivity.java:368)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Answer (score 0):

start BroadcastReceiver name  error  you should contrast  them

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter filterStart =new IntentFilter(ACTION);
context.registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,filterStart);

Intent intent =new Intent(ACTION);
```